# Download all files to a zip within Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, zip

I've been knocking my head around with Heroku, while trying to download a zip file with all my receipt files data.

The files are stored on amazon s3 and it all works fine on my development machine..

I thought it had to do with Tempfile, and abandoned that previous solution, since heroku has some strict policies with their filesystem, so i used the tmp folder, but the problem doesn't seem to be there. I already tried to load directly from s3 (using openUri) to the zip file, but it doesn't seem to work either on Heroku.

What might be wrong with my code for Heroku not loading the files to the zip?

Here is my model method :

```
def zip_receipts(search_hash=nil)

  require 'zip/zip'
  require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

  t=File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand(12).to_s)}_#{Process.pid}",'w')

 # t = Tempfile.new(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand(12).to_s))     

  # Give the path of the temp file to the zip outputstream, it won't try to open it as an archive.
  Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|
   logger.debug("search hash Zip: #{search_hash.inspect}")
     self.feed(search_hash).each do |receipt|
      begin
        require 'open-uri'
        require 'tempfile'

        #configures filename
        filen = File.basename(receipt.receipt_file_file_name)
        ext= File.extname(filen)
        filen_noext = File.basename(receipt.receipt_file_file_name, '.*')
        filen=filen_noext+SecureRandom.hex(10)+ext
        logger.info("Info Zip - Filename: #{filen}")
        # Create a new entry on the zip file
        zos.put_next_entry(filen)
     #    logger.info("Info Zip - Added entry: #{zos.inspect}")
        # Add the contents of the file, reading directly from amazon
        tfilepath= "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{File.basename(filen,ext)}_#{Process.pid}"

      open(tfilepath,"wb") do |file|
        file << open(receipt.authenticated_url(:original),:ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE).read
      end

        zos.print IO.binread tfilepath
      #   logger.info("Info Zip - Extracted from amazon: #{zos.inspect}")
        rescue Exception => e
          logger.info("exception #{e}")
        end  # closes the exception begin
     end #closes receipts cycle
  end #closes zip file stream cycle
  # The temp file will be deleted some time...
   t.close

  #returns the path for send file controller to act
   t.path

  end
```

My controller:

```
 def download_all
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])

    filepath = @user.zip_receipts
    # Send it using the right mime type, with a download window and some nice file name.
    send_file(filepath,type: 'application/zip', disposition: 'attachment',filename:"MyReceipts.zip")
  end
```

And I write also my view and routes, so that it might serve anyone else trying to implement a download all feature

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
 post 'download_all'
end
```

my view

```
<%= link_to "Download receipts", user_download_all_path(user_id:user.id), method: :post %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with the search hash, and the sql query, and not the code itself. For some reason, the receipts get listed, but aren't downloaded. So it is an all different issue

In the end i have this code for the model

```
 def zip_receipts(search_hash=nil)

  require 'zip/zip'
  require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

  t=File.open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/MyReceipts.zip_#{Process.pid}","w")

 # t = Tempfile.new(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand(12).to_s))
  #"#{Rails.root}/tmp/RecibosOnline#{SecureRandom.hex(10)}.zip"

 puts "Zip- Receipts About to enter"
  # Give the path of the temp file to the zip outputstream, it won't try to open it as an archive.
  Zip::ZipOutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|
     self.feed(search_hash).each do |receipt|
      begin
        require 'open-uri'
        require 'tempfile'

        filen = File.basename(receipt.receipt_file_file_name)
        ext= File.extname(filen)
        filen_noext = File.basename(receipt.receipt_file_file_name, '.*')
        filen=filen_noext+SecureRandom.hex(10)+ext
      #  puts "Info Zip - Filename: #{filen}"
        # Create a new entry on the zip file
        zos.put_next_entry(filen)
        zos.print open(receipt.authenticated_url(:original),:ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE).read
        rescue Exception => e
          puts "exception #{e}"
        end  # closes the exception begin
     end #closes receipts cycle
  end #closes zip file stream cycle
  # The temp file will be deleted some time...
   t.close

  #returns the path for send file controller to act
   t.path

  end
```